# develop automated phone dialer in android

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an Android application, the app should make a phonecall to an automated external phone service. Analize the response. Dial some extra numbers accordingly. 
Now I looked around for how to make a phonecall and all I found is a way to invoke a phone activity. I don't want to show the phone ui or play the phone sound. 
I also need to be able to let my app analize it.

I own the phone service and the app is going to be used through my phone. So it is all legal, don't worry.

How do I stream a phonecall to my app?